# ARIMA - Stock Forecast

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

I stumbeled over this [Rstudio Example](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/399202_e78dfd98a7434405893996f2e7cf4b37.html) for Stock Forecasting.

The guy uses daily historical data from Microsoft stocks. However, when creating the Time Series object with the `ts` function, he sets `frequency = 1`:

```
# Daily Seasonality (frequency set to 1 for daily data)
msft <- ts(data[,2],frequency=1)
```

My question is, why `frequency = 1` ? Wouldn't it usually be better to set the frequency to `252` , since the stock market has 252-253 trading days per year?

As follows:

```
msft <- ts(data[,2], start = c(1992,01), frequency = 252)
```

I am still a beginner in RStudio, that's why I'm confused. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of frequency we try to find seasonality in data. Try with different different frequency like hourly , daily , weekly , quarterly ,yearly etc.. Which-ever frequency is giving good accuracy keep it for future forecast.